# Complex SQL from 4 tables

Tags: php, mysql

Please I need some help in writing an SQL statement for a PHP application that involves four tables. Here is the situation.

- Each Art in Table B has a list of categories in Table D
- Each PlaceID in Table A has a list of categories in Table C

I need to select Art from Table B to fill a PlaceID in Table A, but both Art and PlaceID must have at least one category in common.

I will appreciate any help that I can get.

## TABLE A

```
PlaceID | 

1       |  
2       |
```

### TABLE B

```
ArtID | Art

1     | Art1
2     | Art2
3     | Art3
```

## TABLE C

```
ID | PlaceID | Category

1  | 1       | Cat1
2  | 1       | Cat2
3  | 2       | Cat3
4  | 2       | Cat1
5  | 3       | Cat1
```

### TABLE D

```
TabID  | ArtID | Category

1      | 1     | Cat1
2      | 1     | Cat2
3      | 1     | Cat3
4      | 2     | Cat1
5      | 2     | Cat2
```

Comment: So is the catehgories in TABLE C and TABLE D related?  Wouldnt it be better to have a categories table and then have another table which is what joins A +B to categories?

Comment: The categories in Table C and Table D are related, Cat1 is the same in both tables.  I dont understand your point about the joining table.

Comment: The relation between the places and arts are missing, how arts and places relates to each other? Also why you don't use readable names like `Categories, arts, and places` instead of table1, table2, table3?

Comment: I mean with your current design you can't join the four tables in one query, you are missing  a relation between arts and places.

Comment: @  Mahmoud, in my actual application I have real names... now there is no clear relationship between arts and places... the only relationship is that places have some categories allowed and arts fall into several categories. What I need is a list of qualified arts for each place based on categories.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a given **myPlaceID** you can find possible **Art** values as follows:

```
SELECT     DISTINCT B.Art
FROM       B
INNER JOIN D 
        ON D.ArtID = B.ArtID
INNER JOIN C 
        ON C.Category = D.Category
WHERE      C.PlaceID = :myPlaceID;
```

You don't need table **A** in this query.

Here is a [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/48d14c/3). Note that for the existing values for **PlaceID** (1, 2, 3) you will always get 2 records as result (Art1, Art2) with the example data you provided. So you might want to use some other data to get more variation in your results.

Comment: @ trincot, thanks let me run this and see what I get.

Comment: @ trincot, thanks for the response. You solution is quite close to what I want but not exactly.

In the fiddle you sent, when :myPlaceID = 3, Art 1 should not be returned because Art 1 only allows  cat2 and 3, but placeID supports only Cat 1. Please is there a way you can modify the query.. Remember this is the logic...Each PlaceID supports a list of categories.. Only Arts that exist in that category should be allowed.

Thanks for the help

Comment: I don't understand that you say Art1 only allows cat2 and 3, because in your question you list in table D, in its first record that Art1 is related to cat1. Can you clarify?

Comment: ignore my last comment. I was making a mistake. you SQL actually meets my need.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the two tables `tablec` and `tabled` are related with `Category`, then you can do this:

```
SELECT
  b.Art,
  a.PlaceId,
  COUNT(DISTINCT c.Category) AS TotalCategories
FROM tableA AS a 
INNER JOIN tablec AS c ON a.placeID = c.PlaceID
INNER JOIN tabled AS d ON d.Category = c.Category
INNER JOIN tableB AS b ON b.ArtID = d.ArtID
GROUP BY b.Art, a.PlaceId
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT c.Category) > 0;
```

This will give you only the places and arts that has at least one category in common, with count of categories in common.

- [**SQL Fiddle Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/43578/5)

This will give you:

```
|  Art | PlaceID | TotalCategories |
|------|---------|-----------------|
| Art1 |       1 |               2 |
| Art1 |       2 |               2 |
| Art2 |       1 |               2 |
| Art2 |       2 |               1 |
```

As you can see this returned only art 1, 2 with places 1, 2 as they are the only arts and places have more than one category in common.

---

**Side note:** In your table designs, you are missing the many to many junction table between arts and places. So, iF the `category` is just to relate tablec with tabled, then you can get rid of either `tablec` or `tabled`, So that you will have both `placeid` and `artid` in the same table that will act as many to many junction table.